# Upper bounded wildcards causing compilation error in Java

Tags: java, bounded-wildcard

I cannot understand why I am getting these compilation errors:

1:

> The method add(capture#1-of ? extends Exec.Bird) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (Exec.Sparrow)

2:

> The method add(capture#2-of ? extends Exec.Bird) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (Exec.Bird)

```
static class Bird{}
static class Sparrow extends Bird{}

public static void main(String[] args){
    List<? extends Bird> birds = new ArrayList<Bird>();
    birds.add(new Sparrow()); //#1 DOES NOT COMPILE
    birds.add(new Bird());// //#2 DOES NOT COMPILE
}
```

Comment: Regarding #1: with `List<? exitends Bird>` you actually say *any type that is a subtype of `Bird`*. That means that it *can* be a `Sparrow`, but it can also be a `Blackbird`. If you try to add a `Sparrow` to a list that *could* contain only `Blackbird`s, it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `List<? extends Bird>` you actually say *any type that is a subtype of Bird*, or, more accurately, ***an unknown, but specific type that is a subtype of `Bird`***. It's not the same as saying *every type that extends `Bird`*.

That means that `?` can be a `Sparrow`, but it can also be a `Blackbird`. If you try to add a `Sparrow` to a list that *could* contain only `Blackbird`s, it won't work. For that same reason you cannot add a `Bird` to a list that *could* be a List of `Sparrow`s.

In order to make things work, you just change the declaration of the list to this:

```
List<Bird> birds = new ArrayList<>();
```

or use lower bound:

```
List<? super Bird> birds = new ArrayList<>();
```

About this lower bound example: the declaration actually says ***any type that is a `Bird` or one of its superclasses***. That means that you can safely add a `Sparrow` or a `Bird`, because both meet those criteria.

Generally speaking, you should use `? super ...` when you are writing to the list, and `? extends ...` when you are reading from the list. If you are both reading and writing, you shouldn't use bounds.

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4343547/507738) provides very useful information about generics. You definitely should read it.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate the `birds` list like this:

```
List<Bird> birds = new ArrayList<>();
```

Full code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    static class Bird{}
    static class Sparrow extends Bird{}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Bird> birds = new ArrayList<>();
        birds.add(new Sparrow());
        birds.add(new Bird());
    }
}
```