# Adding to list with upper bounded wildcards in java

Tags: java, wildcard, upperbound

Given the following code:

```
public class Test{

    static class Bird{}
    static class Sparrow extends Bird{}
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
    
    List<? extends Bird> list = new ArrayList<Bird>();
   
    list.add(new Bird()); //Does not compile ...line 1
    list.add(new Sparrow());//Does not compile ...line 2
     
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why I cannot add the object of `new Bird()` and the object of `new Sparrow()` into the list? I was expecting line 1 and line 2 to compile since the class `Sparrow` is a subclass of `Bird`, and `Bird` is itself.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2723538/14071914) answer your question?

Comment: Exact duplicate: [Upper bounded wildcards causing compilation error in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44516990/upper-bounded-wildcards-causing-compilation-error-in-java)